# Converting grayscale image to color

Tags: android, graphics

What is the best way to convert a grayscale image (1-pixel/byte) to a color bitmap - using a color space (RGB in form of a byte array)?

I think this would use [ColorMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html) class, but I cannot figure out how to use it achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm for converting from Gray -> RGB is outlined (in my favorite) [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) docs:

RGB->Gray is a weighted sum of R,G,B.
Gray->RGB is a straight copy from Gray Value = R,G,B values (no scaling).

You could just use a int[] and do a double for loop to copy all Gray Values to the RGB array, you could then use [Canvas.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)(int[],width,offset,height,offset,RGB) to draw onto a Canvas.

```
//color[], gray[]
for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++){
      color[x+y*w] = 0xff << 24 | gray[x+y*w] << 16 |  gray[x+y*w] << 8 | gray[x+y*w];
    }
}
// make sure to set hasAlpha to be false, or set the 0xff value to be alpha
//canvas.drawBitmap(color, ...)
```

Even if used the ColorMatrix calss you have to deal with having to copy the GrayScale bits into the [r g  b a] value.  ColorMatrix is really for scaling/converting from ARGB to ARGB.

Comment: Could you please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132772/cannot-get-the-original-colored-bitmap-after-tesseract-processing-android