# Cannot get the original colored bitmap after tesseract processing - android

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb, tesseract, grayscale

I use tesseract library for android to capture certain text from an image. I know that the captured image is not saved anywhere, it gets recycled. I need to find the original colored bitmap. I have been trying to locate the original colored bitmap, but all I could find was a grayscaled bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = activity.getCameraManager().buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height).renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap();
```

When I save this bitmap to the sdcard, I get a gray scaled image. renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap() method is as follows:

```
public Bitmap renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    byte[] yuv = yuvData;
    int inputOffset = top * dataWidth + left;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      int outputOffset = y * width;
      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int grey = yuv[inputOffset + x] & 0xff;
        pixels[outputOffset + x] = 0xFF000000 | (grey * 0x00010101);
      }
      inputOffset += dataWidth;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
  }
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me to get the original colored image captured. Do I have to change this method to get the colored image(RGB)?

Comment: do you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width,
     height, null);
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 80, baos);
   byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
   Bitmap bitmaptest = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
     byteArray.length);

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * YUV to bitmap
     * @param data   The YUV preview frame.
     * @param width  The width of the preview frame.
     * @param height The height of the preview frame.
     * @return
     */
    public static Bitmap byteArray2Bitmap(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
        YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, baos);
        byte[] rawImage = baos.toByteArray();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length, options);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

Comment: You need to write a question. First I recommend you read tutorial for asking!